# How to load a text file from within an XQuery?

Tags: text, xquery, saxon

Is there an XQuery command to load a text file?

I can load an xml document by doing the following;

```
declare variable $text := doc("test.xml");
```

But it only seems to work if test.xml is a well-formed xml document. What I want is to load a plain test.txt file into a string variable. Something like this;

```
declare variable $str as xs:string := fn:loadfile("test.txt");
```

Can it be done?

I'm using the Saxon engine but I can't find an answer in the saxon documentation.

Comment: I think the answer is no with an standar function. The `unparsed-text()` function is an XSLT only function.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you can find one implementation of the file functions in Zorba: http://www.zorba-xquery.com/doc/zorba-1.4.0/zorba/xqdoc/xhtml/www.zorba-xquery.com_modules_file.html

Comment: Maybe I should look into Zorba. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

XQuery 3.0 has the function `fn:unparsed-text` (which was originally defined in XSLT), which does exactly what you want.  XQuery 3.0 is still a work in progress though, but whilst there are not many XQuery 3.0 processors available, many XQuery processors already support this function (including Saxon).

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like exactly what I need, but when I try using it I get an error "System function unparsed-text#1 is not available with this host language". Also the Saxon documentation for fn:unparsed-text() has a disclaimer which says "The current Saxon implementation is not stable: if the function is called twice with the same argument, it will read the external file twice, and may return different results if it has changed."

Comment: You should say that XQuery 3.0 is a Working Draft: even few month ago it had a different version number...

Answer (score 1):

There is a standardization effort for this on EXPath. A spec already exists for an XQuery File module that is capable of doing what you describe: [EXPath File Module Spec](http://expath.org/spec/file).

Yet, I don't know how many implementations are out there. Saxon doesn't seem to implement it unfortunately (Or, please point me to it). An example implementation is shipped with zorba (see [XQDoc Site of Zorba](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/doc/zorba-latest/zorba/xqdoc/xhtml/www.zorba-xquery.com_modules_file.html#read-text-1)). If you want to know how to get started with zorba, you can check out this tutorial: [Get Started with XQuery and Zorba](http://www.xquery.co.uk/tutorial_xquery_get_started/index).

Answer (score 0):

XQuery by default( means fn: namespace ) doesn;t have any file-access methods.

MarkLogic :
xdmp:filesystem-file()
xdmp:filesystem-directory()

Zorba:
  already mentioned by user457056

Exist
  [Exist File Module](http://exist-db.org/extensions.html#module_file)

Answer (score 0):

Saxon since version 9.2 has an extension of fn:collection that can be used to read unparsed text. Here is an example:

```
    collection('file:///c:/TEMP?select=text.txt;unparsed=yes')
```

This is described under "[Changes in this Release](http://saxonica.com/documentation9.2/changes/intro/functions92.html)" for 9.2. Apparently it is not mentioned in the function library documentation. However it works well and I have been using it a lot.